# Verilog Icarus giving undefined values

Tags: verilog, risc, icarus

I'm working on a project in which I'm designing a simple RISC machine in Icarus Verilog 0.9.7.

This code is modular and I'm going to put together the several components in the end, but I've run into an issue while working on the Memory Controller. For all of my test values I'm getting undefined output, or 'Z'. How can I fix this? I don't see any reason why these values are not being populated.

Defining all the behaviors the memory controller should have would be beyond the context of this question, so I'll try to keep it brief and on the topic of Verilog.

Here's my current Verilog code. The workbench has two files, mem.sv and SrcMemoryController.sv:

```
    `default_nettype none

module SrcMemoryController(
    inout [31:0] cpu_bus,
    inout [31:0] mem_bus,
    input ma_in,
    input md_in, 
    input md_out, 
    input read,
    input enable,
    output [15:0] address
);

  reg [31:0] ma = 32'bz;
  reg [31:0] md = 32'bz;
  wire [31:0] cpb = cpu_bus;
  wire [31:0] meb = mem_bus;

  always @(*) begin

    if(ma_in) ma = cpb;

    if(md_in) md = cpb;

    if(read) begin
      if(enable) md = meb;
    end

  end

  assign cpu_bus = (md_out) ? md : 32'bz;
  assign mem_bus = (~read && enable) ? md : 32'bz;
  assign address = ma;

endmodule
```

mem.sv currently works and is not the root of this problem. I will include it anyway incase it helps.

```
`default_nettype none

module Memory (
  inout [31:0] mem_bus,
  input [15:0] address,
  input read, 
  input enable
);

  reg [31:0] storage [65535:0];

  always @(enable) begin
    if(enable) begin
      if(read) begin

      end
      if(!read) begin
        storage[address] = mem_bus;
      end
    end
  end

  assign mem_bus = (read) ? storage[address] : 32'bz;

endmodule
```

Here's the testbench as well. It may not be needed but posting it could help.

```
    `default_nettype none
`include "mem.sv"

module tb_MemoryController;

  wire [31:0] mem_bus;
  wire [31:0] cpu_bus;
  reg [31:0] bus_sim;
  reg bus_sim_out = 0;

  // Tri-state buffer
  assign cpu_bus = bus_sim_out ? bus_sim : 32'bz; 

  reg ma_in, md_in, md_out;
  reg read, enable;
  wire [15:0] address;

  Memory vmem( mem_bus, address, read, enable );
  SrcMemoryController dut( cpu_bus, mem_bus, ma_in, md_in, md_out,
                       read, enable, address );

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("mem_file.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, dut);
    $dumpvars(0, vmem);

    test_memory(0, 0);
    test_memory(10, 0);
    #1 assert_empty(mem_bus);
    #1 assert_empty(cpu_bus);
    test_memory(65535, 65535);
    test_memory(1231, 123);
    test_memory(1231231, 65535);
    test_memory(0, 65535);
    test_memory(100, 100);
    test_memory(515, 515);
    #1 assert_empty(mem_bus);
    #1 assert_empty(cpu_bus);
    $finish();
  end

  task test_memory;
    input [31:0] data;
    input [15:0] addr;
    begin
      #1
      zero_inputs();
      #1
      write_value(data, addr);
      #1
      load_spoof(); 
      #1
      read_value(addr);
      #1
      assertEquals(cpu_bus, data);
      zero_inputs();
    end
  endtask

  task write_value;
    input [31:0] data;
    input [15:0] addr;
    begin
      #1
      enable <= 0;
      bus_sim <= addr;
      bus_sim_out <= 1;
      ma_in <= 1;
      #1
      bus_sim <= data;
      bus_sim_out <= 1;
      ma_in <= 0;
      md_in <= 1;
      read <= 0;
      enable <= 1; 
    end
  endtask

  task read_value;
    input [15:0] addr;
    begin
      #1 
      enable <= 0;
      bus_sim <= addr;
      bus_sim_out <= 1;
      ma_in <= 1;
      #1
      ma_in <= 0;
      read <= 1;
      enable <= 1;
      bus_sim_out <= 0;
      md_out <= 1;
    end
  endtask

  task load_spoof;
    begin
      #1
      bus_sim <= 32'hABCDABCD;
      bus_sim_out <= 1;
      ma_in <= 1;
      md_in <= 1;
      read <= 0;
      enable <= 0; 
      #1
      zero_inputs();
    end
  endtask

  task zero_inputs;
    begin
      ma_in <= 0;
      md_in <= 0;
      md_out <= 0;
      read <= 0;
      enable <= 0;
      bus_sim_out <= 0;
    end
  endtask

  task pulseClock;
    begin
    end
  endtask

  task assertEquals;
    input [31:0] val;
    input [31:0] exp;
    begin
      if (val == exp) $display("[TEST][PASSED] %d", val);
      else $display("[TEST][FAILED] Got %d, expected %d", val, exp);
    end
  endtask


  task assert_empty;
    input [31:0] a;
    begin
      if (a === 32'bz) $display("[TEST][PASSED] (Bus empty)", a);
      else $display("[TEST][FAILED] (Value on bus)", a, 32'bz);
    end
  endtask

endmodule
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This didn't resolve the issue, however. I'll review all of my operands to make sure they're correct.

Comment: Done now, updated both files.

Comment: Alright. That should have fixed it, there must have been an error copying it over. Thanks for helping

Comment: I didn't write the testbench, I'm pretty new to Verilog and haven't been given much material to learn. I analyzed the EPWave and saw the same thing, but the testbench was written by my TA and I know that works.

Comment: Try with `always @(*)` instead of `always @(enable)` for your `Memory` logic block. Also there is no need to create extra wires `cpb` and `meb` you can directly use the `inout` ports

Comment: Noticed one more thing. You should also have `(read && enable)` for your `assign mem_bus` statement in `Memory` module

Comment: Thanks kevin!, the always @(*) fixed it fully. Unfortunately, I can't change the assignment part of mem.sv as the assignment requires a ternary operator to be activated only for read. If you want points post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given in comments by Kevin, I will detail how it was fixed.

I changed the always @(enable) in mem.sv to always @(*), after this was changed the rest of the code started working immediately and with full functionality. Thanks a ton Kevin1494!